# How to disable foregin key generation in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

In my project, I just want to keep the relationship between entities and do not want the Framework to generate foreign key in migration, what can I do please?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you not want the FK?

Comment: FK will decrease the performance and You can't use it as constraints when you need to slice data into different databases.